# serialization usage for array in perl

Tags: perl, sockets

I have perl client and server. I use IO::Socket to send data between them.

client can send any command to the server, server runs it and send the response back to the client  - monitoring like behavior approach.

**client.pl stuff:**

```
# !/usr/bin/perl
use 5.022;
use strict;
use warnings;

#tcpclient.pl

use IO::Socket::INET;

my $addr = shift @ARGV;
my $port = shift @ARGV;

# flush after every write
$| = 1;

my ($socket,$client_socket);

# creating object interface of IO::Socket::INET modules which 
internally creates 
# socket, binds and connects to the TCP server running on the specific 
port.
$socket = new IO::Socket::INET  (
PeerHost => $addr,
PeerPort => $port,
Proto => 'tcp',
) or die "ERROR in Socket Creation : $!\n";

print "TCP Connection Success.\n";

while (1) {
my $msg = <STDIN>;
$socket->send ($msg);

my $res = <$socket>;
print $res;

}

$socket->close();
```

**server.pl stuff:**

```
# !/usr/bin/perl
use 5.022;
use strict;
use warnings;

#tcpserver.pl

use IO::Socket::INET;

# flush after every write
$| = 1;

my ( $socket,      $client_socket );
my ( $peeraddress, $peerport );

# creating object interface of IO::Socket::INET modules which 
internally does
# socket creation, binding and listening at the specified port 
address.

$socket = new IO::Socket::INET->new(
LocalHost => '0.0.0.0',
LocalPort => '55555',
Proto     => 'tcp',
Listen    => SOMAXCONN,
Reuse     => 1
) or die "ERROR in Socket Creation : $! \n";


print "server waiting for client connection on port 55555\n";

while ( $client_socket = $socket->accept() ) {

# waiting for new client connection.

# get the host and port number of newly connected client.
$peeraddress = $client_socket->peerhost();
$peerport    = $client_socket->peerport();

#print "Accepted New Client Connection From : $peeraddress, 
$peerport\n ";

while (<$client_socket>) {

    print "[$peeraddress $peerport] $_";
    my $data = `$_`;
    print $data;

    $client_socket->send($data);

}

}

    $socket->close();
```

Everything is ok in case the output of the command is one string (commands like `uptime`, `uname`, `pwd`). 
If the output contains more strings for e.g. `ip a` I get only one string on the client side.

I find out that in order to resolve the issue we can use serialization approach. In this way we can use array that can be send from the server side with all strings in it.

I've parsed through StackOverflow and found a lot of such approaches:

> [How can I send an array in client server program in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896599/how-can-i-send-an-array-in-client-server-program-in-perl)
>
> [How do I encode a simple array into JSON in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521399/how-do-i-encode-a-simple-array-into-json-in-perl)
>
> [Perl socket sending hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697856/perl-socket-sending-hash)

here is the way I tried to change the client and server side in case `Storable` module usage:

**new server.pl stuff with "Storable":**

```
 # !/usr/bin/perl
 use 5.022;
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 #tcpserver.pl

 use IO::Socket::INET;
 use Storable qw(nstore_fd);


 # flush after every write
 $| = 1;

 my ( $socket,      $client_socket );
 my ( $peeraddress, $peerport );

 # creating object interface of IO::Socket::INET modules which 
 internally does
 # socket creation, binding and listening at the specified port 
 address.

 $socket = new IO::Socket::INET->new(
 LocalHost => '0.0.0.0',
 LocalPort => '55555',
 Proto     => 'tcp',
 Listen    => SOMAXCONN,
 Reuse     => 1
 ) or die "ERROR in Socket Creation : $! \n";


 print "server waiting for client connection on port 55555\n";

 while ( $client_socket = $socket->accept() ) {

 # waiting for new client connection.

 # get the host and port number of newly connected client.
 $peeraddress = $client_socket->peerhost();
 $peerport    = $client_socket->peerport();

#print "Accepted New Client Connection From : $peeraddress, 
$peerport\n ";

while (<$client_socket>) {

    print "[$peeraddress $peerport] $_";

    #serialization approach
    #save command output in array
    my @data = `$_`;
    print @data;

    #store and send the whole array
    nstore_fd( \@data, $client_socket );

}

}

$socket->close();
```

**new client.pl stuff with "Storable":**

```
 # !/usr/bin/perl
 use 5.022;
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 #tcpclient.pl

 use IO::Socket::INET;
 use Data::Dumper;
 use Storable qw(fd_retrieve);

 my $addr = shift @ARGV;
 my $port = shift @ARGV;

 # flush after every write
 $| = 1;

 my ($socket,$client_socket);

 # creating object interface of IO::Socket::INET modules which 
 internally creates 
 # socket, binds and connects to the TCP server running on the 
 specific port.
 $socket = new IO::Socket::INET  (
 PeerHost => $addr,
 PeerPort => $port,
 Proto => 'tcp',
 ) or die "ERROR in Socket Creation : $!\n";

 print "TCP Connection Success.\n";

while (1) {
my $msg = <STDIN>;
$socket->send ($msg);

   #serialization approach
   #retrieve the array 
   while(my $s = $socket ->accept){
    my $struct = fd_retrieve($s);
    print Dumper($struct);
   }

}

$socket->close();
```

But the aforementioned did not work for me.

Could someone advise me how my client side can reflect the multiple output from the server side using serialization in the proper way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling [`accept`](http://p3rl.org/IO::Socket#accept%28%5BPKG%5D%29) is the problem. Get rid of the inner `while` loop and simply read from the socket. In client.pl, you did this with the <> (a.k.a. [readline](http://p3rl.org/readline)) operator, in new_client.pl, `fd_retrieve` will do that implicitly for you.

```
while (1) {
    my $msg = <STDIN>;
    $socket->send($msg);
    my $struct = fd_retrieve($socket);
    print Dumper($struct);
}
```

PS: Upgrade to [IO::Socket::IP](http://p3rl.org/IO::Socket::IP) so you get IPv6 support. Upgrade to [Sereal](http://p3rl.org/Sereal) for [serialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10684780/46395) because Storable is not compatible across different Perl versions.

Comment: ah!so easy. thnx a lot for help.

Comment: I played around code and found out that changing `print Dumper($struct)` to ==> `print $struct ->[0];` gave result without displaying `VAR` and brackets from Dumper, more user-friendly output. Maybe useful for somebody.